# can we view all the routes in emberjs aka something similar to what rake routes does in rails

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

As the routes file in emberjs is becoming large, I am finding it difficult to keep track of all the routes supported by emberjs app, rake routes in rails gives a list of routes in the rails app, is there a way to generate routes in similar fashion for emberjs?

Comment: then this is more like a question for ember.js and not for rails

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently you can access all existing routes with `App.Router.router.recognizer.names` or just the names using `Ember.keys(App.Router.router.recognizer.names)`.

It's obviously not as extensive as the Rails routes but it gives a quick and dirty overview.

Comment: any idea how access routes when the project is using Ember CLI ?

Answer (score 6):

In current versions of Ember/Ember-cli this is `Object.keys(App.__container__.lookup('router:main').router.recognizer.names)`, where `App` is the name of your Ember app.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back off of [Bradley Priest's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365865/bradley-priest) answer, this may seem obvious to seasoned programmers, but for newb's, you can run `App.Router.router.recognizer.names` command in the debug console in the browser (ie: Firebug in Firefox, Chrome Developer Tools, etc...) after you load your Ember app in the browser.

Also note that `App` should be whatever you named your Ember App in the application.js file.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers work anymore.  This works for ember 2.18.2:

`App.__container__.lookup('router:main')._routerMicrolib.recognizer.names`

(again, where `App` is the name of your ember app)

`ember-cli: 2.18.2
node: 6.11.1`