# how to enumerate all route names in an ember test

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-testing

we need to get a list of all route names from `router.js` in a test.  preferably a lower level test (unit/integration).

use case for context: we have metadata that is required for all routes.  this test is to make sure that the appropriate metadata was added, and not forgotten, when a new route is added.

similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756458/can-we-view-all-the-routes-in-emberjs-aka-something-similar-to-what-rake-routes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280145/how-to-get-all-registered-routers-in-ember-version-2-4-6-by-es6) have been asked, but attempts to adopt/modify those solutions within a test have not been fruitful.

Comment: FYI, router.router has been replaced by router._routerMicrolib. The container no longer resides on the application, but the application instance. That's why the existing solution no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I've managed to do it in an acceptance test.

here's what I don't like about this solution:

- it has the higher overhead of an acceptance test.
- it uses private APIs.

the private APIs are used in [ember-inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/blob/master/ember_debug/route-debug.js) though, so if it breaks in the future, we should be able to reference whatever they've changed in that repo.

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('Acceptance | route metadata test', hooks => {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  test('we can get route names', function(assert) {

    const router = this.owner.lookup('router:main');

    router.setupRouter();

    const routeNames = router._routerMicrolib.recognizer.names;
    assert.ok(Object.keys(routeNames).length > 0);

  });
});
```

the test only asserts that we have route names.  for the original use case, it is trivial to change this code to iterate over `routeNames`.

```
ember-cli: 3.5.0
node: 8.12.0
```

the need to call `setupRouter()` was found via [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11610)